# Optimize PHP code to build Tree structure out of large dataset

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, tree

I have a program to populate highest level node or parent node to be populated next to each of the child and grand child nodes.

I have first made a tree structure and then parse through to populate highest level node or root node next to each child/grandchild nodes.

But when I run the program on a large data set >20000 rows i get this error:

```
Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1807745024) (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_project\index.php on line 20
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

include('mysql_config.php');

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
$r = mysql_query("SELECT Emp_ID AS id,fname AS name,Manager_ID AS parent_id FROM targets");
        $data = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
         $data[] = $row;
         }    
$j = mysql_query("SELECT Emp_ID AS id,fname AS name,Manager_ID AS parent_id FROM targets where Type = 'Super Manager'");
        $parent_data = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($j)) {
         $parent_data[] = $row;
         }           

function buildtree($src_arr, $parent_id = 0, $tree = array())
{
    foreach($src_arr as $idx => $row)
    {
        if($row['parent_id'] == $parent_id)
        {
            foreach($row as $k => $v)
                $tree[$row['id']][$k] = $v;
            unset($src_arr[$idx]);
            $tree[$row['id']]['children'] = buildtree($src_arr, $row['id']);
        }
    }
    ksort($tree);
    return $tree;
}

function fetch_recursive($tree, $parent_id, $parentfound = false, $list = array())
{
    foreach($tree as $k => $v)
    {
        if($parentfound || $k == $parent_id)
        {
            $rowdata = array();
            foreach($v as $field => $value)
                if($field != 'children')
                    $rowdata[$field] = $value;
            $list[] = $rowdata;
            if($v['children'])
                $list = array_merge($list, fetch_recursive($v['children'], $parent_id, true));
        }
        elseif($v['children'])
            $list = array_merge($list, fetch_recursive($v['children'], $parent_id));
    }
    return $list;
}
foreach($parent_data as $value)
{ 
echo '<pre>';
$result_data = fetch_recursive(buildtree($data),(int)$value['id']);
print_r($result_data);
echo '</pre>';
  if(!empty($result_data)){
   foreach($result_data as $child_val){
     $su_id=(int)$value['id'];
     $name_man=(string)$value['name'];
     $dest_id=$child_val['id'];
       mysql_query("update targets set SM_ID ='$su_id',SM_Name='$name_man' where Emp_ID='$dest_id'") or die (mysql_error());
     }
    }
}

?>
```

How can i optimize the code to solve this error. I tried this code with 100 rows and it worked fine.

**Original Problem Statement**

I have the following Data in My DB:

```
Manager_ID Employee_ID

AAA   BBB
AAA   CCC
AAA   DDD
BBB   EEE
BBB   FFF
CCC   GGG
FFF   HHH
III   JJJ
JJJ   KKK
JJJ   LLL
```

I wish to populate the child nodes with their respective highest level roots nodes such that all child nodes have a root level data/parent mapped to them something like this:

```
Employee_ID 1st Level Node
AAA         Root
BBB         AAA
CCC         AAA
DDD         AAA
EEE         AAA
FFF         AAA
GGG         AAA
HHH         AAA
III         Root
JJJ         III
KKK         III
LLL         III
```

I have tried creating a PHP function to create a tree but am unable to take it from there to populate the last or highest level root to the respective child nodes.

Comment: If you are trying to build the entire tree, why are you surprised that memory get's exhausted?

Comment: Not surprised. Just out of ideas on how to solve this issue.I am forced to use PHP or else it would have been a cake walk in JAVA.

Comment: Don't be so sure about Java being able to do this either. It's very unusual to want to build a complete tree in a web app

Comment: Your problem statement isn't clear at all, but I hope this will set you on the right track http://stackoverflow.com/a/37288233/267540

Comment: That gives a better perspective. Thanks. I've also updated my problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb:  PHP has 40 bytes of overhead for each scalar value.  That adds up fast.

Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` interface; use either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Solution to your problem:  Put all the data into temporary MySQL tables, then use SQL statements to rearrange into the hierarchical format.  Ah; you seem to have the data already in a table.

The SQL would involve one SQL statement per level of the hierarchy, probably doing all records at that level in a single statement.  PHP code would control the levels, since MySQL has no concept of hierarchy.

Quite possibly this change will even run faster that PHP would have -- you end up with a small number of queries, instead of the 20000 (or more) you currently are designed for.

Here's a way to transform your code.  Start with the innermost `for` loop.  Think about how that loop can be turned into *one* SQL statement.  Then do it.  (You may be happy enough after this one step.)

Answer (score 0):

First add a column to your table for each child's root ID:

```
ALTER TABLE targets ADD COLUMN Root_ID INT;
```

Then set the root ID to the manager's ID:

```
$sql = "UPDATE targets SET Root_ID = Manager_ID";
if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
    error_log($conn->error);
    die("Database error occurred, see log.");
}
```

Then iteratively update the root ID to that employee's manager's ID. The loop stops when no changes are made, because there is no child left whose root ID itself has a manager. At this point, all records will have their root ID set to an employee record that has no manager (i.e. root employees).

```
$affectedRows = 1;
while ($affectedRows > 0) {
    $sql = "UPDATE targets AS child
        INNER JOIN targets AS parent
          ON child.Root_ID = parent.Emp_ID
        SET child.Root_Id = parent.Manager_ID";
    if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
        error_log($conn->error);
        die("Database error occurred, see log.");
    }
    $affectedRows = $conn->affected_rows;
    echo "Changed $affectedRows rows\n"; // demo only, remove this echo
}
```

Now you can print out the employees with their roots, row by row, without having to store all the data at any one time:

```
$sql = "(SELECT Emp_ID, Root_ID FROM targets)
    UNION
    (SELECT t1.Manager_ID, 'Root' FROM targets AS t1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN targets AS t2 ON t1.Manager_ID = t2.Emp_ID
     WHERE t2.Emp_ID IS NULL)
    ORDER BY Emp_ID";
if (($result = $conn->query($sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) === false) {
    error_log($conn->error);
    die("Database error occurred, see log.");
}
printf("%-10s %-10s\n", "Emp_ID", "Root_ID");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf("%-10s %-10s\n", $row["Emp_ID"], $row["Root_ID"]);
}
$result->free();
```

Output:

```
Emp_ID     Root_ID   
AAA        Root      
BBB        AAA       
CCC        AAA       
DDD        AAA       
EEE        AAA       
FFF        AAA       
GGG        AAA       
HHH        AAA       
III        Root      
JJJ        III       
KKK        III       
LLL        III
```

---

Re your comment:

To optimize this, I added an index `PRIMARY KEY (Emp_ID, Manager_ID)`. Here's my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `targets` (
  `Manager_Id` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `Emp_Id` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `Root_ID` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Emp_Id`,`Manager_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Here's the query EXPLAIN for the UPDATE:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               id: 1
      select_type: UPDATE
            table: child
       partitions: NULL
             type: ALL
    possible_keys: NULL
              key: NULL
          key_len: NULL
              ref: NULL
             rows: 10
         filtered: 100.00
            Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
               id: 1
      select_type: SIMPLE
            table: parent
       partitions: NULL
             type: ref
    possible_keys: PRIMARY
              key: PRIMARY
          key_len: 3
              ref: test.child.Root_ID
             rows: 1
         filtered: 100.00
            Extra: Using index
```

Here's the EXPLAIN for the SELECT UNION:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: targets
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: UNION
        table: t1
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 6
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: UNION
        table: t2
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 3
          ref: test.t1.Manager_Id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Not exists; Using index
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: NULL
  select_type: UNION RESULT
        table: <union1,2>
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: NULL
     filtered: NULL
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: This solution is taking over 8 hours for a mere 5000 records. For 20,000 it would take much longer. Any advice on how to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly recreating the tree in memory is not working. The simple self referencing table is indeed a simple and obvious solution to the problem of describing a tree in a relational database, but as you have discovered, it is also very limited. This would be relatively easy if your data was stored in an [adjacency list](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

If we have even a single field we can update, then its possible to flag the trees iteratively, something like....

```
 run_query('update yourtable set flag=0');
 foreach ($root_id as $root) {
     $d=1;
     run_query('update yourtable set flag=$d where id=$root');
     do {
        $rows_changed=run_query('update yourtable y1 
           set y1.flag=$d+1
           where y1.parent in (select y2.id from yourtable y2
             where y2.flag=$d');
        ++$d;
     } while ($rows_changed);
     run_query('update yourtable set root=$root, flag=0
        where flag>0');
 }
```

(Note code not tested).

Of course this can be implemented as in a mysql procedure which will run slightly faster than a mixed php/mysql solution.

Comment: What is $root_id  here?

Comment: An array containing the identifiers of the root records.

Comment: ('update yourtable y1 
           set y1.flag=$d+1
           where y1.parent in (select y2.id from yourtable y2
             where y2.flag=$d'))
Error here : Table 'targets' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: I did say it wasn't tested - so copy the ids to a temp table.