# Get child of child recursively php

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, hierarchy

i have a table with two columns id and parent id

[image: data base image]

I want to get a recursive result child of child of child and so on 
here in this example i want to achieve a result like

parent_id = 2

[image]

means first time parent is 2
next time result will be as parent 
like 4,5,6,15 was id and 2 is parent id
next time 4,5,6,15 will be used as parent id
and result will be id = 7,8,13,14,16 and their id = 4,5,6 and 15

this will continue until last child.

Comment: I think you can achieve this by just using ORDER BY. Have you tried WHERE parent_id >= 2 ORDER BY parent_id, id ASC?

Comment: @L.Herrera This doesn't work, as ID 10 has a parent_id of 3 and is not listed but would be a result of a your updated query.

Comment: order by will not work
i want to get child of child

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37288233/267540

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can help you

```
   <?php
$serverName = "localhost"; //serverName\instanceName

// Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"jdih");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}



function count_data($var)
{
    $serverName = "localhost";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"jdih");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) total from test where parent_id = '".$var."'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    $rowChild = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rowChild['total'];
}



$sql = "SELECT id from test where parent_id = 0";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) { 
    $totalchild = count_data($row['id']);
    if($totalchild > 0){
        $sqlchild = "select id from test where parent_id = '".$row['id']."'";
        $stmtchild = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlchild);
            while( $rowChild = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtchild, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
                //
                    $totalchild2 = count_data($rowChild['id']);
                    if($totalchild2 > 0){
                        $sqlchild2 = "select id from test where parent_id = '".$rowChild['id']."'";
                        $stmtchild2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqlchild2);
                        while( $rowChild2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtchild2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
                            echo $row['id']. ' Has ' . $rowChild['id'].' has '.$rowChild2['id']. '<br>';
                        }

                    }else{
                        echo $row['id']. ' Has ' . $rowChild['id'].'<br>';
                    }
            }
    }else{
        echo $row['id']. ' Has nothing';
    }

}



?>
```

here is an example,i'm using sql. It's not dynamic but if only two level maybe it will help. You can add `conditional check` if that has child.

[image]

sorry bad english