# Matching parent to child in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have a family tree table containing names, ids, and genders of family members, and another table that has a parent column and a child column containing ids. I am trying to find the parent-child relationship and I am having some difficulty getting the query right. For example, I want to find the father of 'John', so my query is:

```
`select name from tree inner join relationship on id=parent where gender='m' and name="John"...`
```

That is not right and I am confused on where to go from here. Basically I want to select the name of the male parent of John, and eventually extend the query out to select John's mother and father. How would I formulate my query to search for John's parents given their names and relationship (via parent and child columns)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287868/get-sum-from-nodes-tree/37288233#37288233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you would need two references to the `tree` table.

Without a definition of the tables and example data, we're just guessing.

```
  SELECT p.name
    FROM tree p
    JOIN relationship r
      ON r.parent = p.id
    JOIN tree c
      ON c.id = r.child
   WHERE p.gender = 'm'
     AND c.name = 'John'
```

assuming (for example)

```
tree

id    name  gender
----  ----  ------
 402  John  m
 399  Adam  m
```

and

```
relationship

parent  child
------  -----
   399    402
```

Comment: It will very kind of you @spencer7593 if you can explain the joins being done by giving example of each table created after each joins. Thanks in advance.